# Selectively performing mathematical calculation on InstrumentedAttribute in Flask/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working with the Flask / SQLAlchemy ORM and what I'd like to do is to perform mathematical calculations selectively on instances of `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute`. An equation like this would look something like `User.query.update({User.score: User.points / User.time})`.

For example, let's say I have > 100,000 entries in my PostgreSQL database that looks something like this: `User.points` --> [12, 3, 0, ..., 45]; `User.time` --> [102, 23, 45, ..., 12] (please note the `0` in `User.points`). In the example below, I would get an exception stating I cannot take the logarithm of 0.

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
from project.models import User


User.query.update({User.score: func.log(User.points / User.time)})
```

I'd like to selectively choose which `InstrumentAttribute` to perform calculations on. I can use `User.query.filter` to filter a query, but how would I transform this into a filtered model without performing calculations iteratively, if you will?

Comment: why you can't use something like `.where(User.points > 0)` ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this works, unless I'm interpreting this differently: `User.query.update({User.score: func.log(User.points / User.time)}).where(User.points != 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.session.query(User).where(User.points != 0).update({User.score: func.log(User.points / User.time)})
// or
User.query.filter(User.points != 0).update({User.score: func.log(User.points / User.time)})
db.session.commit()
```

logs:

```
2021-07-20 20:20:25,750 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-07-20 20:20:25,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE "user" SET score=log("user".points / "user".time) WHERE "user".points != %(points_1)s
2021-07-20 20:20:25,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00046s] {'points_1': 0}
2021-07-20 20:20:25,764 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE "user" SET score=log("user".points / "user".time) WHERE "user".points != %(points_1)s
2021-07-20 20:20:25,764 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00055s] {'points_1': 0}
2021-07-20 20:20:25,766 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Wow didn't know it was this simple. Thanks a lot

Comment: As an update, if you're worried the mathematical output (in my case the quotient) will cause trouble, you can write: `User.query.filter((User.points / User.time) > 0).update({User.score: func.log(User.points / User.time)})`